# Header navigation slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm doing a header that looks like this:
Header bar with logo and arrow down indicating a navigation. if you hover the header, the navigation slides down and you see the big columns, now i'm trying to make that if you click a column more specific links will slide down.

I've managed to have the sublink bar be on the same css top value as the column link for the downsliding to look smooth, but now i don't know how to add in the toggle value.

This is the javascript, please tell me what's wrong.

```
var top = ($('#serviceslink').top()+toggle);
var toggle = 0;
$('#serviceslinkextended').css({'top':top+'px'});
$('#serviceslink').click(function(){
    if (toggle == 0) {toggle = 30}
    else {toggle = 0}
});
```

edit: if (toggle == 0)

edit3: is this better?

```
var top = $('#serviceslink').top();
var toggle = 0;
$('#serviceslinkextended').css({'top':top+toggle+'px'});
$('#serviceslink').click(function(){
    if (toggle == 0) {toggle = 30}
    else {toggle = 0}
});
```

edit4:
i realised that the subcolumn only stayed on the same height because no top value was defined,
that doesn't seem to work on every browser though. I used slideToggle now but it's just not the same, i want to know how it works this way.

Comment: `if (toggle = 0)` You need `==` there, not `=`.

Comment: `if (toggle = 0) {toggle = 30}` Why did you think that the *same* operation does *different* things in different contexts?

Comment: *"is this better?"* Does it work? If not, it's not much better. Also you are using jQuery, which is a library.

Comment: @FelixKling You seem to know a whole lot about javascript, give me the solution then. "Also you are using jQuery, which is a library." I realised that now, too, thanks. I'm new to this whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this functions:

```
$(selector).slideUp()
$(selector).slideDown()
```